# UIImageView zoom and pinch in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have tried many different ways of implementing expand image and pinch to zoom. I have found tutorials on how to do this with images saved in my project however I am retrieving my images from Firebase. I would like one image to take about half the ProfileViewController screen and the other pictures to be able to be expanded full page and also have the ability to zoom. My code I have for it now does this however the zooming and the position is not clean or easy to use.

```
var newImageView: UIImageView!



@IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)


    newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .top
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0

    scrollView.addSubview(newImageView)

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
{
    return newImageView;
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

[image: profilePageView]

[image]

Comment: what is the problem in screenshot there are many issues in screenshot.

Comment: @KKRocks I have not designed it yet, I just am focusing on how to make each image expand when clicked, and also be able to zoom correctly after is it already expanded.

Comment: then what you want to do ?

Comment: @KKRocks   Find a more efficient way to display the images, when I click on images the view and the frame is totally off.

Comment: use this library for zoom imageView : https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController

Comment: @KKRocks can you help me use this in swift, I'm not sure how to convert it

Answer (score 0):

Here is I am creating scrollview and imageview programatically and here **img** is a `PHAsset` that I am selecting image from gallery.

Here what I am doing, select an image and move to other view controller and I resize that image according to my imageview 
So image is not blurry after zooming it. 
Minimum zooming is imageview bound and maxmimum zooming is 4.0.

```
func singleVC1()  {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 80, height: view.frame.size.height - 200))
        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: v.frame.size.width, height: v.frame.size.height/2 - 1))
        let scroll1 = UIScrollView.init(frame: view1.bounds)
        let imgview = UIImageView.init(frame: (CGRect)(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.returnAspectSize(targetWidth: view.frame.size.width, img: img)))
        self.setZoomScale(scrollview: scroll1, imageview: imgview)
        imgview.image = self.getUIImage(asset: img)
        scroll1.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
        scroll1.delegate = self;
        scroll1.bounces = false
        scroll1.contentSize =  imgview.frame.size
        scroll1.addSubview(imgview)
        view1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view1.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        view1.addSubview(scroll1)
        v.addSubview(view1)

        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: v.frame.size.height/2+1, width: v.frame.size.width, height: v.frame.size.height/2 - 1))
        let scroll2 = UIScrollView.init(frame: view2.bounds)
        let imgview1 = UIImageView.init(frame: (CGRect)(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.returnAspectSize(targetWidth: view.frame.size.width, img: img)))
        imgview1.image = self.getUIImage(asset: img)
        self.setZoomScale(scrollview: scroll2, imageview: imgview1)
        scroll2.bounces = false

        scroll2.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
        scroll2.delegate = self;
        view2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view2.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        scroll2.contentSize = imgview1.frame.size
        scroll2.addSubview(imgview1)
        view2.addSubview(scroll2)
        v.addSubview(view2)
        self.view.addSubview(v)
    }
func setZoomScale(scrollview : UIScrollView, imageview : UIImageView) {
        var minZoom = min(self.view.bounds.size.width / imageview.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / imageview.bounds.size.height);

        if (minZoom > 1.0) {
            minZoom = 1.0;
        }
        scrollview.minimumZoomScale = minZoom;
        scrollview.zoomScale = minZoom;
    }
    func returnAspectSize(targetWidth : CGFloat, img : PHAsset) -> CGSize {
        let img1 = self.getUIImage(asset: self.img)
        let targetwidth = targetWidth
        let scalefactor = (CGFloat)(targetwidth) / (CGFloat)((img1?.size.width)!)
        let targetheight = (img1?.size.height)! * scalefactor
        let targesize = CGSize(width: (CGFloat)(targetwidth), height: targetheight)
        return targesize
    }
```

Try this. I am sure this will help you.

Comment: should i be putting this into my imageTapped gesture recognizer function?

Comment: means what do you want to do ? Is this working properly ? @hghg

Comment: I would like to add it to every image, and some profiles may only have 2-3 images

Comment: it seems that you have to add scoll for all images that you add into scrollview so as according to my answer you can calculate frames for it and add imageview as much as you can

Comment: can i send you my project so you understand better what I mean?

Comment: yeah sure, Give me dropbox link so I can download your project @hghg

Comment: do you have an email i can send it to instead of posting on here? if you don't mind