# Zoom in a Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, zooming

I'm a bit confused. I followed the recommendation given by Apple to zoom in a scroll view, but nothing happens.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

        func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing something. However, the function to scroll vertically or horizontally works well. But when I press "option" and move the 2 grey dots, no zoom happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43200996/1292099

Comment: Check out my answer into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624834/uiimageview-zoom-and-pinch-in-uiscrollview/43626273#43626273. Its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed wrong name for delegate method. Seems you copied that code from previous version of Swift. In Swift 3 it should be:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
```

Be careful with such mistakes it can waste so much time. I recommend you to type every delegate method once again "viewforzoom..." and auto complete will show you the right one.

Comment: just another question, it seems the viewForZooming protocol requires to return a UIView. However I have an array of UIImageVIew created in my scrollView, and I would like to return them, is it possible ?
In my case I tried :


    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> ([UIView]) {

        return postItTable

    }

 with postItTable = [UIIMageView]()

Comment: viewForZooming is not a protocol. Protocol called UIScrollViewDelegate and it defines exact methods your class (ScrollViewController) should implement. Protocol has only "viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?" for that purposes so scroll view can ask your view controller only for this. I think you need something like that: add some view and add image views in that view as subviews. and method above will return that view.