# Scrollview only zooms to upper left corner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uiscrollview

I've created a scrollview programmatically and added an image as it's subview but when I try to zoom into the image it only zooms into the upper corner and it doesn't let me scroll around to see different parts of the image.

Here's the code I used to create the scrollview:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()

var image: NSData!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.image = UIImage(data: image as Data)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(share))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap(recognizer:)))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

func share(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        if UIImage(data: image as Data) != nil {
            let Item = UIImage(data: self.image! as Data)
            let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [Item!], applicationActivities: nil)
            activity.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.openInIBooks]
            self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func handleDoubleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.maximumZoomScale, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any kind of help

Comment: where is imageview frame?

Comment: AS per your question please Check out my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624834/uiimageview-zoom-and-pinch-in-uiscrollview/43626273#43626273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your code when you set the zoomscale of your scrollView. You don't specify where it should zoom to. So naturally, it zooms and stays in the top left corner.

You need to get the location of the touch in your `handleDoubleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)`, calculate the rect for zoom, and call `scrollRectToVisible` on your scrollview.

Comment: The handleDoubleTap is just used for when the user double taps that it's gonna zoom in or out. But it also just zooms to the upper left corner when I simply zoom in with my fingers.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout or constraints?

Comment: Yes I used constraints for the imageView that's in the scrollview

Comment: If you use constraints, then it will take it back to the top left corner. Don't use constraints.

Comment: Thank you that actually helped me. I also created the imageview programmatically.